# Window.open() does not work on safari IOS 16

Tags: async-await, safari, mobile-safari, window.open, issue-tracking

I am using JavaScript **window.open()** method to open new window inside of *async* function, it works well in IE, Firefox, chrome, brave but not working in *safari* for mobile.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => 
    if(response){
      const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      window.open(url)
    }
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution for above problem for all browsers with all OS (IOS, android and windows, linux).
It's working for me.

```
function downloadBlobFile(blob, fileName) {
    //Check the Browser type and download the File.
    const isIE = !!document.documentMode;
    if (isIE) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
        const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        const link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        a.setAttribute("href", link);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
}

fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => 
    if(response){
      const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/octetstream" });
      downloadBlobFile(blob, "test.pdf")
    }
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```